# Very easy short riddle

Tags: riddle

> I am fast
>
> I "*revive*" many things
>
> People will need me
>
> Although I am dangerous to people.

What am I?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is it

> Electricity?

I am fast

> as lightning

I "revive" many things

> CLEAR!

People will need me

> He's going into cardiac arrest!

Although I am dangerous to people.

> I SAID CLEAR!

Comment: You defeated me haha, great job

Answer (score 4):

You are

> An answer :P

I am fast

> As the riddle is easy, the answer is supposed to come quickly.

I "revive" many things

> An answer could "revive" an old problem, if not many of them.

People will need me

> Obviously you need an answer when you ask the question

Although I am dangerous to people.

> Seeing the answer will either ruin your own one, or just make you feel bad that you haven't guessed it yet.

Comment: Good answer :D but sadly, it is not the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Are you:

> Oxygen?

**Explanation:**

I am very fast

> The oxygen in air moves very quickly during high winds/hurricanes.

I revive many things

> Not sure about this one.

People will need me

> Without oxygen, we would die.

But I am dangerous to people

> Pure oxygen can be toxic.

Comment: Nope, I have edited the question a bit, see if you can find anything :P (Sorry for my bad English)

Answer (score 1):

Could it be

drugs? They can be quick, they can revive things, people do need them, but too much can cause an overdose and kill you.